# Regex pattern to detect any possible way built in Node.js to fetch a resource via http

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I know in Node.js we can fetch a resource via http using `http.get()` or `http.request()` e.g.

```
http.get('https://example.com', (contents) => {
    contents.pipe(res);
});
```

I need a regex pattern to be able to detect in JS code whether the code has any of possible ways built in Node.js to fetch a resource via http regardless of how exactly a developer may write it using white spaces or new lines e.g.

```
http. get  (
```

or

```
http.
get    (
```

All these ways are still working

At the moment I wrote the following regex pattern

```
'/\.(\s+)?(get|request)(\s+)?\(/'
```

I don't use the variable `http` in the pattern as a developer may use any name of the variable e.g. `server`

Is there anything I should add or change? Maybe there is one more built-in way I don't know about?

I mean only ways which are built in Node.js (out-of-the-box) and not third-party frameworks or modules

Comment: Please explain why you need that. (It is not possible to detect every way to fetch http resource using RegExp)

Comment: Your code doesn't work for this `http['agteft'.split('')'.filter((_, i) => i % 2 == 1).join('')].call` and variations

Comment: @t.niese To detect whether a developer fetches http resource in his code. Why is it not possible?

Comment: How do you want to detect even simple things link that`let test = http; test.test = test.get; test.test(`

Comment: Also, since node 17, you can use built-in `fetch`

Comment: Or a basic socket used to implement the http protocol instead of using http module.

Comment: @t.niese Ok, I see. Maybe there is a solution how to block any requests from Node.js to http resources? Maybe a module. I mean allow only access to the filesystem

Comment: As others mentioned there are many ways to access network resources from a Node.js script. Maybe restrict the running process? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83348/537986

Comment: @PeterThoeny Thanks! Maybe you know where can I read the same also for Windows?

Comment: @stckvrw: Sorry, I don't